# Snapshot isolation transaction failed in database 'tempdb' because the object accessed by the statem

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, isolation-level, transaction-isolation, snapshot-isolation

I have set **allow_snapshot_isolation** and **READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT** on my application database. I have SP's which use temp tables. In case of concurrent access on of the SP throws below error.
None of the SP have alter temp table command , i mean it is not updating any metadata.

The same scenario works fine in SQL 2008 R2 but not in SQL 2017

"Snapshot isolation transaction failed in database 'tempdb' because the object accessed by the statement has been modified by a DDL statement in another concurrent transaction since the start of this transaction.  It is disallowed because the metadata is not versioned. A concurrent update to metadata can lead to inconsistency if mixed with snapshot isolation.
Uncommittable transaction is detected at the end of the batch. The transaction is rolled back."

Comment: Can you post the code?  Or better yet a simplified repro?

Comment: Do you ALTER permanent tables in the proc? That would explain the error.